# Jenkins not executing Windows Batch command java x.y.file$test

Tags: java, jenkins

Been searching all day for why Jenkins does not execute a Windows batch command
    java x.y.java$Test

If you open windows cmd and execute java x.y.java$Test it works just fine. I can execute the cmd from any directory and the java is executed.

CLASSPATH is the same when I view Jenkins Environment variables or the systems variables. I'm running Windows 7

Running Jenkins 2.138.1

Here is the error message:

Error: Could not find or load main class bichromate.core.sTestCleanupFactory$Test

any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: Have you tried running inside the batch a `java -version` or a `echo %cd%`?

Comment: Can you share the error logs?

Comment: Do an `echo PATH` and see whats the difference

Comment: command is:

java bichromate.core.sTestCleanupFactory$Test

Error message added: 

Error: Could not find or load main class bichromate.core.sTestCleanupFactory$Test

All works well when run from the CMD prompt from any directory

if I look at CLASSPATH for JENKINS  and WINDOWS they are the same

Thank you again for all the support.

Answer (score 0):

So it works in jenkins if you add the -cp

EXAMPLE:  java -cp path to the class **then** the qualified class file